# WSDoAllReceiver: Incoming message does not contain required Security header

Tags: c#, java, web-services

I have java service which communicates over https. I want to connect to this service from C#.

I am getting this exception:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   WSDoAllReceiver: Incoming message does
>   not contain required Security header.

Someone knows what is wrong?

C# Code:

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(
                    new Uri("https://JavaStore:8443/JavaStore/services/B2BService"),
                        EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("JavaStore"),
                        new AddressHeaderCollection()
                );

BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

var client = new ReharB2BService.B2BServicePortTypeClient(binding, address);;

client.Open();
client.getAllItems();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this post on how to include security headers in WCF calls (the example is against a java hosted web service): http://isyourcode.blogspot.com/2010/05/using-oasis-username-token-profile-in.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring web service you need to add securityInterceptor.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Value("${client.default-uri}")
private String defaultUri;

@Value("${client.user.name}")
private String userName;

@Value("${client.user.password}")
private String userPassword;

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.example.eppmsoapclient");
    return marshaller;
}


@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor security = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    security.setSecurementActions("UsernameToken");
    security.setSecurementUsername(userName);
    security.setSecurementPassword(userPassword);
    security.setSecurementPasswordType("PasswordText");
    return security;
}

@Bean
public SOAPClient soapClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    SOAPClient client = new SOAPClient();
    client.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[]{ securityInterceptor() });
    return client;
}

}



public class SOAPClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

 public Response doExecute(Request request) {
    
     Response response = (Response) getWebServiceTemplate()
              .marshalSendAndReeive(request);
    
     return response;
    
 }
}
```

Required dependencies :

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```